# Querying objects from 1:M related Models DRF

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Designed a Django Model with multi-level 1:M relations, able to get the json response writing Serializers in DRF. It looks easy to perform CRUD operations but only particular to that table, I am expecting response something similar to the response below , then came across a term called **Nested Serializers**, As I am not much aware of that, can someone suggest me to have one for the below model

```
{
  "Blocks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A",
      "Floor": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": 0,
          "count":2,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "White Tiger"
            },
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "The Alchemist"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": 1,
          "count": 2,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Facebook"
            },
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "The Master Blaster"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "B",
      "Floor": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": 0,
          "count":2,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Know Your self"
            },
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "The Naga"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": 1,
          "count":2,
          "books": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "The Data Analyics"
            },
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Become Master of R"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Whenever a book is added/deleted, it should be reflected in *count* attribute on the Floor

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships), for read-only, something like this should work:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book

class FloorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    book = BookSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Floor

class BlockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Floor = FloorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Block
```

[For writing/updating,](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) write create and/or update -methods to the BlockSerializer.

```
class BlockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Floor = FloorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Block

    def create(self, validated_data):
        floors_data = validated_data.pop('Floors')
        block = Blocks.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for floor_data in floors_data:
            books_data = floor_data.pop('books')
            floor = Floor.objects.create(block=block, **floor_data)
            for book_data in books_data:
                Book.objects.create(floor=floor, **book_data)
```

Hope this helps